# Swift4 毎日の起動時間

Tags: swift, swift4

Swift4を使用しています。端末の電源を入れてからの起動時間をとることはできました。次に、一日にどれだけ起動していたかという値をとりたいと思いました。翌日になったら行う処理というものが、なかなか見つからず困っております。どうかお教えいただきたいです。

Comment: そういうこともiOSではできません。

Answer (score 2):

iOSのアプリは、アプリが起動していない場合や、アプリがバックグラウンドで起動している場合に

- 特定の時間に処理を行うこと
- タイマー等を利用して一定周期で処理を行うこと

は、できません。これは iOS の仕様です。

> 次に、一日にどれだけ起動していたかという値をとりたいと思いました。

単に一定周期で処理を実行したいだけ、というのであれば、外部にサーバを立てて、端末に向かって一定周期でサイレントプッシュを送信する、とかも考えられますが、それは one no さんの目的に合致していますでしょうか？（違う気がします）

何のためにこのような事(1日の起動時間を調べる)をやりたいと考えているのかを開示されると、one no さんの目的の解決に近ずくのではないかと思います。